# Mixing Adsense and Facebook Audience Network

Tags: google-adsense

I have a website and on the mobile version I want to use both Adsense and Facebook Audience Nework?
It is possible? I can't find any info on both sites.

Comment: Want to do the same. Not finding any resource.